# I am stuck with registration/login in php...passwords are not matching when login-using hash('sha256',$password)

Tags: php

```
<?php
//<!--Start session-->
session_start();
include('connection.php'); 

//<!--Check user inputs-->
//    <!--Define error messages-->
$missingUsername = '<p><strong>Please enter a username!</strong></p>';
 $missingEmail = '<p><strong>Please enter your email address!</strong></p>';
$invalidEmail = '<p><strong>Please enter a valid email address!</strong></p>';
$missingPassword = '<p><strong>Please enter a Password!</strong></p>';
$invalidPassword = '<p><strong>Your password should be at least 6 characters long and inlcude one capital letter and one number!</strong></p>';
$differentPassword = '<p><strong>Passwords don\'t match!</strong></p>';
$missingPassword2 = '<p><strong>Please confirm your password</strong></p>';
//    <!--Get username, email, password, password2-->
//Get username
if(empty($_POST["username"])){
    $errors .= $missingUsername;
}else{
    $username = filter_var($_POST["username"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);   
}
//Get email
if(empty($_POST["email"])){
    $errors .= $missingEmail;   
}else{
    $email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $errors .= $invalidEmail;   
    }
}
//Get passwords
if(empty($_POST["password"])){
    $errors .= $missingPassword; 
}elseif(!(strlen($_POST["password"])>6
         and preg_match('/[A-Z]/',$_POST["password"])
         and preg_match('/[0-9]/',$_POST["password"])
        )
       ){
    $errors .= $invalidPassword; 
}else{
    $password = filter_var($_POST["password"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    if(empty($_POST["password2"])){
        $errors .= $missingPassword2;
    }else{
        $password2 = filter_var($_POST["password2"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if($password !== $password2){
            $errors .= $differentPassword;
        }
    }
}
//If there are any errors print error
if($errors){
    $resultMessage = '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $errors .'</div>';
    echo $resultMessage;
    exit;
}

//no errors

//Prepare variables for the queries
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $username);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $email);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $password);
//$password = md5($password);
$password = hash('sha256', $password);
//$password= password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
//128 bits -> 32 characters
//256 bits -> 64 characters
//If username exists in the users table print error
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if(!$result){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Error running the query!</div>';
//    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . mysqli_error($link) . '</div>';
    exit;
}
$results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($results){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">That username is already registered. Do you want to log in?</div>';  exit;
}
//If email exists in the users table print error
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if(!$result){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Error running the query!</div>'; exit;
}
$results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($results){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">That email is already registered. Do you want to log in?</div>';  exit;
}
//Create a unique  activation code
$activationKey = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
    //byte: unit of data = 8 bits
    //bit: 0 or 1
    //16 bytes = 16*8 = 128 bits
    //(2*2*2*2)*2*2*2*2*...*2
    //16*16*...*16
    //32 characters

//Insert user details and activation code in the users table

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (`username`, `email`, `password`, `activation`) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password', '$activationKey')";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if(!$result){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">There was an error inserting the users details in the database!</div>'; 
    exit;
}

//Send the user an email with a link to activate.php with their email and activation code
$message = "Please click on this link to activate your account:\n\n";
$message .= "http://maths.offyoucode.co.uk/activate.php?email=" . urlencode($email) . "&key=$activationKey";
if(mail($email, 'Confirm your Registration', $message, 'From:'.'rajeshsunil107@gmail.com')){
       echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Thank for your registring! A confirmation email has been sent to $email. Please click on the activation link to activate your account.</div>";
}

        ?>
```

**This is my signup code ..signup code is hashing and it's fine and storing into database ...can you please check the code for...The below code is login code **

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();
//Connect to the database
include("connection.php");
//Check user inputs
    //Define error messages
$missingEmail = '<p><stong>Please enter your email address!</strong></p>';
$missingPassword = '<p><stong>Please enter your password!</strong></p>'; 
    //Get email and password
    //Store errors in errors variable
if(empty($_POST["loginemail"])){
    $errors .= $missingEmail;   
}else{
    $email = filter_var($_POST["loginemail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
}
if(empty($_POST["loginpassword"])){
    $errors .= $missingPassword;   
}else{
    $password = filter_var($_POST["loginpassword"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}
    //If there are any errors
if($errors){
    //print error message
    $resultMessage = '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $errors .'</div>';
    echo $resultMessage;   
}else{
    //else: No errors
    //Prepare variables for the query
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $email);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $password);
//$password = hash('sha256', $password);
$password = hash('sha256', $password);
//$password=password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        //Run query: Check combinaton of email & password exists
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password' AND activation='activated'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if(!$result){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Error running the query!</div>';
    exit;
}
        //If email & password don't match print error
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count !== 1){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Wrong Username or Password</div>';
}
else {
    //log the user in: Set session variables
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $_SESSION['user_id']=$row['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['username']=$row['username'];
    $_SESSION['email']=$row['email'];

    if(empty($_POST['rememberme'])){
        //If remember me is not checked
        echo "success";
    }else{
        //Create two variables $authentificator1 and $authentificator2
        $authentificator1 = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(10));
        //2*2*...*2
        $authentificator2 = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(20);
        //Store them in a cookie
        function f1($a, $b){
            $c = $a . "," . bin2hex($b);
            return $c;
        }
        $cookieValue = f1($authentificator1, $authentificator2);
        setcookie(
            "rememberme",
            $cookieValue,
            time() + 1296000
        );

        //Run query to store them in rememberme table
        function f2($a){
            $b = hash('sha256', $a); 
            return $b;
        }
        $f2authentificator2 = f2($authentificator2);
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $expiration = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() + 1296000);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO rememberme
        (`authentificator1`, `f2authentificator2`, `user_id`, `expires`)
        VALUES
        ('$authentificator1', '$f2authentificator2', '$user_id', '$expiration')";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        if(!$result){
            echo  '<div class="alert alert-danger">There was an error storing data to remember you next time.</div>';  
        }else{
            echo "success";   
        }
    }
}
    }

 ?>
```

Th above code is my login code ...where it showing the wrong username and password when i login with same username and password as with signup username and password

Comment: The way I see it, the issue is with your activation code. During sign-up, you're generating and storing a unique id whereas, during log-in, you're checking for a string: 'Activated'.

Comment: It is fine....In my database it is showing Activated

Comment: `sha256` is a simple string hash and is not cryptographically secure, especially when not used with a random salt. You should change it in favor of using the default PHP  [`password hashing functions`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php) In addition, you should change your code to use  [`prepared statements`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). With the prepared statements there is no longer a need to use `filter_var` or `mysqli_real_escape_string` on the user input.

Comment: In order to validate a user login, you would retrieve the hashed password value from the database by using `WHERE email = ? AND activation = 'activated'`, and compare the hash using `password_verify($_POST['password'], $row['password'])` Assuming you are using a database and table character set that has the suffix `_ci` and the column is not modified to be case-sensitive. Otherwise the values in your `WHERE` criteria would be case sensitive, and you would need to use `Activated` instead of `activated`.

Comment: Classic example of why not to create your own password verification system.